# JOIN - сборка данных в один массив

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

`... SELECT * FROM table LEFT JOIN ip using(qid) ...`

```
(
 qid => 1,
 ip => 111.111.11.11
)

(
 qid => 1,
 ip => 222.222.22.22
)
```

как вы видите, они дублируются при одинаковым `qid`, конченый результат должен быть таким:

```
(
 qid => 1,
  ip => array(
   [0] => 111.111.11.11
   [1] => 222.222.22.22
  ) //[111.111.11.11, 222.222.22.22]
)
```

пост с идентификатором 1, посмотрели юзеры с ip `[111.111.11.11, 222.222.22.22]`
то есть все собрать в один массив. Как мне добиться такого результата?

Или нужно строить конечные автоматы, для парсинга массивов?

Comment: можно использовать group_concat, тогда все ip будут в одном поле, в коде останется только разбить строку по разделителю. Хотя ничего плохого в простом цикле по записям не вижу. Т.е. пробежали по записям и сформировали массив в нужной вам форме

Comment: `group_concat` ограничен по длине. Его, конечно, можно исправить, увеличить, но это не самый лучший вариант

Answer (score 1):

Вот такой вариант подойдет?

```
$result = Array();
foreach($rows=>$row) {
    if (!array_key_exists($row["qid"], $result)) {
        $result[$row["qid"]] = Array();
    }
    $result[$row["qid"]][] = $row["ip"];
}
```

Пролистывает сквозь все результаты (можно использовать `fetch` комнады), и создает массив нужного Вам вида.